# How to fill array with random values 1-110

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random

I want to fill tab[110] array with random bits (so 1 and 0). Don't know how to fill with values 1-110, but not 0-109.
My for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<tab.length; i++)
            {

                Random r = new Random();
                tab[i] = r.nextInt(2);
                if (i%25==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+", ");

            }
```

I know that usually it's simple, just tab[i]=i+1;, but when i put a random number into array it doesn't work for me. I tried to add "+1" everywhere in this loop and only effect i got is when i added it to System.out.println - but then i got fake output that it's 1-110, when in array it's still 0-109.

whole code:

```
package teleinformatykalab2;

import java.util.Random;

public class TeleinformatykaLab2 {

    public static void losujBity(int tab[])  // Funkcja losuje ciag 110 bitow i umieszcza je w utworzonej tabeli
    {
        System.out.println("Ciag 110 bitow: ");

        for (int i = 0; i<tab.length; i++)
        {

            Random r = new Random();
            tab[i] = r.nextInt(2);
            if (i%25==0)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+", ");

        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    private static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int x)  // Funkcja zwraca liczby, ktore sa kolejna potega liczby 2
    {
        //return (x & (x-1)) ==0;                
        return (x!=0) && ((x&(x-1)) ==0);
    }

    public static void wyswietlBityPowerOfTwo(int tab[])
    {
        boolean [] bityPotegiDwa = new boolean[7];
        System.out.println("Bity, ktorych indeks w tablicy jest kolejna potega liczby 2: ");
        for (int i=0; i<tab.length; i++)
        {

            if (isPowerOfTwo(i))
                {
                 int j = 0;
                 bityPotegiDwa[j+1] = isPowerOfTwo(i);
                 j++;
                 System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+", ");

                }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void podzielCiagNaParzysteGrupy(int tab[]) // Funkcja dzieli ciag bitow na 7 grup wg indeksow potegi 2
    {
        int [] gr1 = new int [56];


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] tab = new int [110]; // Utworzenie tablicy jako globalnej zmiennej
        losujBity(tab);

        wyswietlBityPowerOfTwo(tab);
        podzielCiagNaParzysteGrupy(tab);


    }

}
```

[edit]
Is this proper method? Make tab[111] and then fill it from i=1 to i<=110?

```
for (int i = 1; i<=110; i++)
        {

            Random r = new Random();

            tab[i] = r.nextInt(2);
            if (i%25==0)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+", ");

        }
```

But then what about tab[0]? Is there null?

[edit2]
My previous version of trying to implement a Hamming code was:

```
package teleinformatykalab2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class TeleinformatykaLab2 {

    //Funkcja wypelniajaca tablice ciagiem losowych bitów 0 lub 1 //

    static boolean[] bity;

    public static void Losowanie(int tab[]){

        ////int [] tab = new int[110];

        for (int i = 0; i<110; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            tab[i] = r.nextInt(2);
            if (i%25==0)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+", ");

        }
        System.out.println("");

}
    /////////////////


    //Funkcja wywietla bity, których indeks w tablicy jest wartoci¹ kolejnej potêgi liczby dwa//
    public static void zamienBity(int tab[], int tabBit[])
    {
        ////System.out.println("\n"+tab[0]+tab[109]+"\n");
        //int [] power = new int [7];
        bity = new boolean[7];
        for (int i=0; i<110; i++)
        {

            if (isPowerOfTwo(i))
                {
                 int j = 0;
                 bity[j] = isPowerOfTwo(i);
                 j++;
                 System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+", ");

                }
            if (i%50==0)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }

        System.out.println("\n");

    }

    //Sprawdzenie ci¹gu kodem Hamminga//
    public static void sprawdzHamming(int tab[], int tabBit[])
    {
        // przypisanie do tabBit bitow o indeksie potêgi dwa
        int [] power = new int [7];
        for(int i=0;i<tabBit.length;i++)
        {
            tabBit[i] = tab[(int)Math.pow(2,i)];
            System.out.print(tabBit[i]+", ");
        }
        System.out.println("////\n");

        //sprawdzenie pierwszej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nPierwsza para");

        int [] skip = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,36,39,41,43,45,47,49,
                        51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,97,99,
                        101,103,105,107,109};    
        for (int i : skip)
        {
             System.out.print(tab[i] + "("+i+")"+",");

                if (i%25==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
        System.out.println("");

        //sprawdzenie drugiej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nDruga para");

         int skip2 []= {3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,22,23,26,27,30,31,34,35,38,39,42,43,46,47,
                        50,51,54,55,58,59,62,63,66,67,70,71,74,75,78,79,82,83,86,87,90,91,94,95,98,99,102,103,106,107};
          for (int j : skip2)
          {
          System.out.print(tab[j] + "("+j+")"+",");
          if (j%25==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
          }
        System.out.println();

        //sprawdzenie trzeciej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nTrzecia para");

         int skip3 []= {5,6,7, 12,13,14,15, 20,21,22,23, 28,29,30,31, 36,37,38,39, 44,45,46,47,
                        52,53,54,55, 60,61,62,63, 68,69,70,71, 76,77,78,79, 84,85,86,87, 92,93,94,95, 100,101,102,103, 108,109};
          for (int k : skip3)
          {
          System.out.print(tab[k] + "("+k+")"+",");
          if (k%18==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
          }
        System.out.println();

         //sprawdzenie czwartej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nCzwarta para");

         int skip4 []= {9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16, 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32, 41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,
                       57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64, 73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80, 89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,
                       105,106,107,108,109};
          for (int l : skip4)
          {
          System.out.print(tab[l] + "("+l+")"+",");
          if (l%8==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
          }
        System.out.println();

        //sprawdzenie pi¹tej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nPi¹ta para");

        for (int m=17; m<110; m++)
        {
            if ((m>=32 && m<=47) && (m>=64 && m<=79) && (m>=96 && m<=111)) continue;
            System.out.print(tab[m] + "("+m+")"+",");
            if (m%16==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
        System.out.println();

        //sprawdzenie szótej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nSzóta para");

        for (int m=33; m<110; m++)
        {
            if (m>=65 && m<=96)/* && (m>=64 && m<=79) && (m>=96 && m<=111))*/ continue;
            System.out.print(tab[m] + "("+m+")"+",");
            if (m%16==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
        System.out.println();

        //sprawdzenie siódmej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nSiódma para");

        int [] sixtyfour = new int [120];

        for (int m=65; m<110; m++)
        {
            //if (m>=65 && m<=96)/* && (m>=64 && m<=79) && (m>=96 && m<=111))*/ continue;
            System.out.print(tab[m] + "("+m+")"+",");
            if (m%16==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");




    ////Tablica liczników par bitów//
        int [] counter = new int [7];

    ////Tablica wywietlanych b³êdów//
        Boolean [] error = new Boolean [7];

        Boolean [] errors = new Boolean [7];
  //////////Liczniki bitów jedynkowych////        
        int licznik1=0;
        for (int a=1; a<110;a++)
        {
            if (tab[a]==1)
                licznik1++;
        }
        int l1;
        String spr;
        if (licznik1%2==1) l1=1; else l1=0;
        if (l1==tabBit[0]) {
            error [0] = true;
            errors[0] = true;
        }//spr="ok";
        else {
            error [0]=false;
            errors[0] = false;
        }
        counter [0] = l1;

        System.out.println("W grupie 1: "+licznik1+"("+tabBit[0]+")" + " >"+counter[0]+" "+error[0]);



        int licznik2=0;
        for (int b=3; b<108;b++)
        {
            if (tab[b]==1)
                licznik2++;
        }
        int l2;
        if (licznik2%2==1) l2=1; else l2=0;
        if (l2==tabBit[1]) {
            error [1]=true;
            errors [1]=true;
        }
        else {
            error [1]=false;
            errors [1] = false;
        }
        counter [1] = l2;
        System.out.println("W grupie 2: "+licznik2 +"("+tabBit[1]+")"+" >"+counter [1]+" "+error[1]);


        int licznik3=0;
        for (int c=5; c<109;c++)
        {
            if (tab[c]==1)
                licznik3++;
        }
        int l3;

        if (licznik3%2==1) l3=1; else l3=0;
        if (l3==tabBit[2]) {
            error[2]=true;
            errors [2] = true;
        }
        else {
            error[2]=false;
            errors [2] = false;
        }
        counter [2] = l3;
        System.out.println("W grupie 3: "+licznik3 +"("+tabBit[2]+")"+ " >"+counter[2]+" "+error[2]);


        int licznik4=0;
        for (int d=9; d<109;d++)
        {
            if (tab[d]==1)
                licznik4++;
        }
        int l4;

        if (licznik4%2==1) l4=1; else l4=0;
        if (l4==tabBit[3]) {
            error[3]=true;
            errors [3]=true;
        }
        else {
            error[3]=false;
            errors[3]=false;
        }
        counter[3]=l4;
        System.out.println("W grupie 4: "+licznik4 +"("+tabBit[3]+")"+ " >"+counter[3]+" "+error[3]);
        //if (l4==tabBit[3]) System.out.print(" ok");

        int licznik5=0;
        for (int e=17; e<110;e++)
        {
            if (tab[e]==1)
                licznik5++;
        }
        int l5;

        if (licznik5%2==1) l5=1; else l5=0;
        if (l5==tabBit[4]) {
            error[4]=true;
            errors [4]=true;
        }
        else {
            error[4]=false;
            errors [4]=false;
        }
        counter[4] = l5;
        System.out.println("W grupie 5: "+licznik5 + "("+tabBit[4]+")"+" >"+counter[4]+" "+error[4]);


        int licznik6=0;
        for (int f=33; f<110;f++)
        {
            if (tab[f]==1)
                licznik6++;
        }
        int l6;

        if (licznik6%2==1) l6=1; else l6=0;
        if (l6==tabBit[5]) {
            error[5]=true;
            errors[5]=true;
        }
        else {
            error[5]=false;
            errors[5]=false;
        }
        counter [5] = l6;
        System.out.println("W grupie 6: "+licznik6+"("+tabBit[5]+")"+" >"+counter[5]+" "+error[5]);


        int licznik7=0;
        for (int g=65;g<110; g++)
        {
            if (tab[g]==1)
                licznik7++;
        }
        int l7;

        if (licznik7%2==1) l7=1; else l7=0;
        if (l7==tabBit[6]) {
            error[6]=true;
            errors[6]=true;
        }
        else {
            error[6]=false;
            errors[6]=false;
        }
        counter [6] = l7;
        System.out.println("W grupie 7: "+licznik7+"("+tabBit[6]+")"+" >"+counter [6]+" "+error[6]);

        //Tablica boolean ok lub b³¹d//
        ArrayList<Boolean> true_or_false = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Boolean tof : true_or_false)
        {
            int i=0;
            i++;
            true_or_false.add(error[i]);
            System.out.print(tof+",");

        }

        /*//Dwuwymiarowa tablica bitów i poprawnoci
        int [][] bit_check = new int [7][7];
        int [] myInt = new int [7];
        for (int i=0,j=0; i<7; i++, j++)
        {
            if (i==0) System.out.println("dwuwymiarowa tablica");
            if (errors[i]==false)
            {
                myInt[i]= (errors[i]) ? 1 : 0;
                bit_check[i]=counter;
                bit_check[j]=myInt;
                  System.out.print(bit_check[i][j]+",");
            }
        }*/

        ////sumowanie par, które sa blêdne////
        ArrayList<Integer> error_sum = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("\n"); 


        for (int i=0, j=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            if (error[i]==false)

            {
                //System.out.println(counter[i]+" "+error[i]);

                error_sum.add(counter[i]);
                    System.out.println(counter[i]+", ");

            }

                //System.out.print("//"+power[j]+", ");
                //System.out.println("Bity zacne: " + bity[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (Integer num : error_sum)
        {
            System.out.print(num+", ");
        }
               //System.out.println("\n"+error_sum[0]+","+error_sum[1]+","+error_sum[2]+","+error_sum[3]+","+error_sum[4]+","+error_sum[5]+","+error_sum[6]);
         System.out.println("\n");

       ////Sumowanie indeksów b³êdnych bitów//
         ArrayList<Integer> error_sum_pair = new ArrayList<>();

         /*for (Integer num : error_sum_pair)
         {
             do{
                 System.out.print();
             }
             if (true_or_false==false)
         }*/
     ////Wskazanie blednego bitu, przez sumowanie blednych par bitow//
         int suma=0;
         int [] grupa = new int [7];
         grupa[0] = 1;
         grupa[1] = 2;
         grupa[2] = 4;
         grupa[3] = 8;
         grupa[4] = 16;
         grupa[5] = 32;
         grupa[6] = 64;

    for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
    {        
        if (i==0) System.out.print("Numery blednych bitow w grupach: ");
        if (error[i]==false) 
        {
            System.out.print(grupa[i]+", ");
            suma+=grupa[i];
        }

            if (i==6) System.out.println("\nIndeks blednego bitu w ciagu: "+suma);
    }     

    int wskOfIndex;
    for (int i=0, j=0; i<110; i++)
    {
        if (j>6) break;
        if (i==grupa[j]) System.out.println("Bledny bit we wskazanym "+suma+" indeksie: "+tab[i]);
        /*wskOfIndex=Arrays.asList(tab).indexOf(grupa[i]);
        if (i==109) System.out.println(wskOfIndex);*/
    }

    /*////Podmiana blednego bity na prawidlowy//
    for (int i=0; i<110; i++)
    {
        if (i==suma)
            {
             if (tab[i]==0) tab[i]=1;
             else tab[i]=0;
            };
    }

    ////Ponowne wygenerowanie, teraz juz prawidlowego ciagu bitow//
    for (int i=0; i<110; i++)
    {
        if (i%25==0)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+", ");
    }

        System.out.println("\n");        
    System.out.println("W grupie 1: "+licznik1+"("+tabBit[0]+")" + " >"+counter[0]+" "+error[0]);
    System.out.println("W grupie 2: "+licznik2 +"("+tabBit[1]+")"+" >"+counter [1]+" "+error[1]);
    System.out.println("W grupie 3: "+licznik2 +"("+tabBit[2]+")"+" >"+counter [2]+" "+error[2]);
    System.out.println("W grupie 4: "+licznik2 +"("+tabBit[3]+")"+" >"+counter [3]+" "+error[3]);
    System.out.println("W grupie 5: "+licznik2 +"("+tabBit[4]+")"+" >"+counter [4]+" "+error[4]);
    System.out.println("W grupie 6: "+licznik2 +"("+tabBit[5]+")"+" >"+counter [5]+" "+error[5]);
    System.out.println("W grupie 7: "+licznik2 +"("+tabBit[6]+")"+" >"+counter [6]+" "+error[6]);*/


}





////Funkcja wypisujaca bity o indeksie w tablicy kolejnej potegi 2// 
    private static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int x)
    {
        //return (x & (x-1)) ==0;                
        return (x!=0) && ((x&(x-1)) ==0);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] tab = new int[110];


    // wywo³anie metody wype³niaj¹cej tablicê ci¹giem losowych bitów 0 lub 1
        Losowanie(tab);
        System.out.println("\n Bity potegi dwa: ");
        int [] tabBit = new int [7];


        zamienBity(tab,tabBit);

        System.out.println("////Bity potegi 2");
        sprawdzHamming(tab,tabBit);
        //powerOfTwo();

        /*int liczby [] = new int[120];
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int z=1; z<120;z++)
        {
            liczby[z]=z;
            System.out.print(liczby[z]+", ");
            if (z%32==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }*/

    }
}
```

But i noticed that some arrays are wrong built (i forgot that arrays are numbered from 0) and i wanted to rebuild this code, so that i ask how to put random 110 bits into array, but with first bit on 1 index (not standard 0).

Comment: An array with 110 items is numbered from 0 to 109. You don't want to do 110 or you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: So how to get 110 random bits (1 and 0) in array? Do tab[111] array and then move iterator +1?

Comment: What exactly do you want? You are talking about *random bits*, but then you want to have the number from 1 to 110. It is one or the other. Either something random or something deterministic. Both at the same time is not possible.

Comment: I also don't see a problem. Your for-loop at the top doesn't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I want put row of 110 random 1 and 0 bits, so "1000110110001".

Comment: @Chris92 Okay. Please [edit your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) and add this information. And while you are on it, please show us the result you get.

Comment: its because i want this random bits to be put in array from index 1. Because later i do other things to apply hamming code, so i divide this row (as array) of bits in 7 groups (because 110 bits has got 7 indexes which are equal to 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 - so next power of two). May seem to be complicated, but i did it, however i messed up with array and it couldnt properly run hamming code.

Comment: @Chris92 instead of putting information in the comments, please state clearly, what you want and do so by editing your question, so everybody sees this information. Maybe give an example. And explain or show which kind of output your algorithm is producing. Otherwise your question will be closed as *not clear what you are asking*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java arrays are indexed starting from 0. So the index of the 1st element will be 0 and index of the N*th* element will be N-1. So since you need to keep 110 bits in an array the arrays will be indexed from 0 - 109.

As an work aground for your requirement of referring to  the elements in   index that starts from 1, you may write some methods to access the array via 1 based index.

e.g.

```
int getArrayValue(int[] array, int index){
  return array[index-1]
}

void setArrayValue(int[] array, int index, int value){
   array[index -1] = value;
}
```

So that your for loop will logs as follows

```
for (int i = 1; i<=110; i++)
{

   Random r = new Random();

   setArrayValue(tab, i,r.nextInt(2));
   if (i%25==0)
   {
       System.out.println("");
   }
   System.out.print(getArrayValue(tab, i)+"("+i+")"+", ");

 }
```

You can use these methods across your code when you want to access the arrays in a 1 based index.

Comment: Thank you. So to use your method with getter and setter, i have to create normal array[110] and put there this values? And access to them will be more comfortable, because if i'd want value from index 5 (in array 4 index), then this value shows up like it is from index 5 (in fact from index 4)? Briefly i call it intuitive, but program will know that it is n-1 index?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, your understanding is correct. You can just create an array[N] and access it using suggested methods using index 1 to N. These methods will convert 1 based index into 0 based index which Java uses.

Comment: Ok, so i just wanted to be able to call this values intuitive, but stated (described) it unclearly. Thus instead of forcing array to start (unnaturally) from 1 index, these values can be stored naturally (as for array from 0 index) and at the same time i can call them intuitive (naturally for human). Thank you again.